# Close the particular JInternalFrame on button click

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I am creating more than one `JInternalFrame` in the `JDesktopPane`.  Each frame having one button.  I want to close the particular frame on which button is clicked.

```
internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("Internal Frame", true, true, true, true);

    internalFrame.setSize(300, 300);
    internalFrame.setLocation(xPosition * openFrameCount, yPosition
            * openFrameCount);

    internalFrame.setContentPane(createContentPane());
    internalFrame.setJMenuBar(createPopJMenuBar());

    internalFrame.setVisible(true);

    JButton close = new JButton( "Close Me!" );  
    close.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {  
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
                try {
                    internalFrame.setClosed( true );
                } catch (PropertyVetoException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
        }  
    } );  
    internalFrame.add( close );  
    jdpDesktop.add(internalFrame);
```

By using the above code I am able to close the last created frame.  Other frames are not closed.

Comment: I want to close the particular JFrame on which button is clicked. ---> my question JFrame or JInternalFrame, could be quite different

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have `internalFrame` as a field of the enclosing class. Then it gets overwritten every time you create a new one. Use a local variable instead:

```
// Notice "final"
final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("Internal Frame", true, true, true, true);
...
```

That ensures that the `internalFrame` in each action listener refers to the one created a few lines above, not to the last created frame.

Comment: great man..it works fine.Can i able to do the same thing using menu in each jframe ?

Comment: @Raja I don't know what do you mean with the menues :-) It's quite possible that you have the same bug pattern there. If you are binding a listener to a menu created locally but assigned it to a field, that seems likely. Generally it's good idea to use local variables unless you actually need to store it in a field.